# rotate a line in actionscript/flex 4.0?

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4, line, transformation

I want to rotate a line around a point in flex 4.0, i tried rotationX and all but whole line rotates and center of point is lost. How to rotate only one end point of line keeping the other constant?

Can someone point to example or explain how to do it? I'm a newbie in flex, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the Rotate effect you are using, make sure `autoCenterTransform` is set to true.

[Look here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/effects/Rotate.html) for more information.